# Developing UWP apps. Do I need to include SDK extension for each version of Windows 10?

Tags: uwp

App is targeted to 10.0.14393.0, 10.0.15063.0, and 10.0.16299.0.  Do I need to include all three extensions for each device or does latest extension include the API's of all previous ones and is the only one I need?  I have searched around and haven't found any conclusive answer elsewhere.

This is first question I have asked here since have always found answer here to previous thousand questions or so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to reference the version of the extension SDKs that correspond to your targetversion (max version tested), not to your minversion (or any version in between the two).